# Is there a way to reuse an argument in fmt.Printf?

Tags: go, printf

I have a situation where I want to use my `printf` argument twice.

```
fmt.Printf("%d %d", i, i)
```

Is there a way to tell `fmt.Printf` to just reuse the same `i`?

```
fmt.Printf("%d %d", i)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use the `[n]` notation to specify explicit argument indexes like so:

```
fmt.Printf("%[1]d %[1]d\n", i)
```

Here is a full example you can experiment with: http://play.golang.org/p/Sfaai-XgzN

Comment: If you are using this to replace a different format like `%s`, remember to swap out the `d` in this answer for `s`. I.e. `fmt.Printf("%[1]s %[1]s\n", i)`

Comment: this is also available for all formated prints, like `Sprintf` and `Fprintf`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [text/template](//pkg.go.dev/text/template):

```
package main

import (
   "strings"
   "text/template"
)

func format(s string, v interface{}) string {
   t, b := new(template.Template), new(strings.Builder)
   template.Must(t.Parse(s)).Execute(b, v)
   return b.String()
}

func main() {
   i := 999
   println(format("{{.}} {{.}}", i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a Printf format string containing multiple % verbs would require the same number of extra operands, but the [n] “adverbs” after % tell Printf to use the nth operand over and over again.

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    a := 1
    fmt.Printf("%d %[1]T\n", a) //1 int

    b, c := "apple", 3.14
    fmt.Printf("%s %[1]T %g %[2]T", b, c) //apple string 3.14 float64
}
```